# Zend Framework 2 unit testing using CodeCeption

Tags: unit-testing, zend-framework2, codeception

We are currently using CodeCeption to do some acceptance testing, but I would like to also add unit testing to the current setup.

Has anyone done Unit testing in Zend Framework 2 project using CodeCeption? And if so, how did you set up the environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this in codeception docs: http://codeception.com/docs/modules/ZF2

There is an example in this github project: https://github.com/Danielss89/zf2-codeception

Comment: Thanks! This is what I used to solve this problem. The example project was VERY useful!

Comment: Looking at that example github project. What does that unit test...test? It tests mock objects. It doesn't test any code. It doesn't access a module or anything. That is not a helpful example. Also, the codeception document on ZF2 doesn't explain anything about unit testing. It contains a long list of methods for accessing pages through a browser like "amOnPage" and "canSee". Sorry for writing this in frustration, but this didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using PHPUnit. I followed the Zend PHPUnit guide, http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/tutorials/unittesting.html, which only got me so far. But, I was able to bootstrap Zend using a phpunit.xml file and pointing that to _bootstrap.php. Codeception is also able to bootstrap my tests using the _bootstrap.php file. So, now I can run my tests using both:

phpunit --bootstrap tests/unit/_bootstrap.php

and

php vendor/bin/codecept run unit

I was surprised to see how few examples there are for this. I was writing tests for a job queue client. Here is a bit of my test:

```
protected function setUp()
{

    $this->serviceManager = new ServiceManager(new ServiceManagerConfig());
    $config = Bootstrap::getConfig();        

    $this->serviceManager->setService('ApplicationConfig', $config);
    $this->serviceManager->get('ModuleManager')->loadModules();

    $this->client = $this->serviceManager->get('jobclient');
    $this->client->addServers(array(array('ip' => '127.0.0.1', 'port' => '666')));
}

public function testServiceCreateSuccess() {

    $this->client->setQueue($this->testData['queue']);

    $this->assertEquals($this->client->getQueue(), $this->testData['queue'], 'We get the expected queue');
}
```

I mocked the job client and had a local config. My _bootstrap.php file looks basically the same as the Zend example except that I am using factories defined in the service config to manage some objects. So, I performed the "setService" method in the test setup rather then in the bootsrap init.